# How do i loop through an array of structs? "TypeError: Integer constant expected." Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

**What i want my code to do**

Everytime the function is called the exampleValue of all users should be increased by 5

**What the code actually does**

When i compile it in Remix i get this error message:

> TypeError: Integer constant expected. User[i].value = User[i] + 5; ^

**Code**

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract LoopingThroughArray {
    
    struct User {
        uint256 exampleValue;
        address id;
        
    }
    
    User[] public users;
    
    receive() external payable {
        for (uint i=0; i<=users.length; i++) {
            User[i].exampleValue = User[i] + 5;  // thats the line where i get the error
        }  
    }
    
    
}
```

**What i already tried**

- replacing the users.length with a constant uint both in- and outside of the function
- using a normal function instead of the receive function

Answer (score 1):

You have reference the mapping name at the index you want, which is a `struct` and the struct member for the math operations.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.0;

contract LoopingThroughArray {
    
    struct User {
        uint256 exampleValue;
        address id;
        
    }
    
    User[] public users;
    
    receive() external payable {
        for (uint i=0; i<=users.length; i++) {
            users[i].exampleValue = users[i].exampleValue + 5;
        }  
    }    
}
```

**CAUTION**

I realize this is a contrived example for learning but it is worth mentioning for others who find this example. This approach won't scale. So, either there is a hard limit on `users.length` or the contract will fail when `users.length` is too large. This is because the total cost is the cost of one iteration times the number of users in the array. So.

transaction cost = iteration cost * numbers of users

Since there is a soft limit to the gas users would be willing to pay and a hard limit on the gas used by a single transaction in a block, it's not a scalable pattern.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! That it wont scale is something i havent thought about. Are there any resources you could recommend about scaling and gas cost of different different operations?

Comment: Ethereum makes you turn to classical (pre-database) data organization. Have a look at this. Other patterns include linked-list. There are even b-trees to use (with caution). It's very common to use mappings for random access, O(1) lookups. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity

Comment: More about the problem and some fresh ways to think about it: https://blog.b9lab.com/getting-loopy-with-solidity-1d51794622ad:

Comment: Your example hints are "process amortization" which is very advanced. Simply put, you have to make sure every function has a fixed gas cost at any scale, O(1). So, for things like "do this for all users" you have to invert control - when each user supplies gas, do this to their state. Have a look at this example of how to tackle such things. https://medium.com/@weka/dividend-bearing-tokens-on-ethereum-42d01c710657